# Який переклад посади "medical writer" буде найбільш точним?

Tags: переклад, from-english, словосполучення

Зіткнулась з необхідністю перекласти назву посади і професії "**medical writer**", яка є поширеною у західній Європі та Америці і починає розвиватись у нас.

Для кращого розуміння зазначу, що означає це поняття англійською:

[1.](http://www.jobhero.com/medical-writer-job-description/#)

> Medical writers use scientific knowledge and writing skills to
>   effectively and clearly communicate *technical medical science
>   information in writing*.

[2.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_writing)

> *A medical writer*, working with doctors, scientists, and other subject matter experts, *creates documents that* effectively and
>   clearly *describe research results, product use, and other medical
>   information*.

Дослівним перекладом буде "*медичний письменник*", але значення українського слова "письменник" не збігається із потрібним для конкретно цього випадку. А отже і таке словосполучення не передасть змісту.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pysjmennyk) та [Тлумачний словник української мови](http://eslovnyk.com/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) дають наступне визначення:

> ПИСЬМЕ́ННИК, а, чол. Той, хто пише *художні твори*; особа, для якої
>   літературна діяльність є професією.

На мою думку, воно не відповідає тому сенсу, який вкладений у поняття "medical *writer*", оскільки мова йде про наукову та публіцистичну літературу, аналіз досліджень та підготовку висновків до них і т.д., в той час як слово "письменник" передбачає написання саме художніх творів.

*То який переклад "medical writer" на українську буде найбільш точним?*

Comment: Як на мене, то
Діловод – це особа, яка приймає, надсилає і сортує документи, листи та інші ділові папери за ступенем важливості; не стосується створення статей і т.д.
Писар - застаріле і не передбачає створення чогось на підставі аналізу певних даних.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Medical writer є частковим випадком [technical writer](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_writer) — тобто людини, що пише технічну документацію, а не художні твори.

Переклади «technical writer»:

- [«Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» Є. Мейнаровича і М. Кратка (2010)](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=technical+writer&dicts=2&highlight=on):

  > реда́ктор техні́чної документа́ції
- [«Загальний народний англійсько-український словник» на E2U](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=technical+writer&dicts=1&highlight=on):

  > розро́бник технічної документа́ції, технічний автор⚠, технічний письменник⚠
- [Вікіпедія (станом на 2018-03-29)](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80&oldid=21531987):

  > техні́чний а́втор, техні́чний письме́нник

Здається, статті «автор» і «письменник» у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах просто застаріли (можливо, у 1970-х роках поняття «технічного автора/письменника» ще не було остаточно оформленим або достатньо поширеним) —  але довести це важко.

У будь-якому випадку, для «medical writer» наразі маємо такі пропозиції:

- медичний автор;
- медичний письменник;
- редактор медичної документації;
- розробник медичної документації.

<sub>Ще від мене:

  • автор медичної документації;

  • відповідальний за медичну документацію;

  • складач медичної документації;

  • укладач медичної документації;

  • упорядник медичної документації.</sub>